# CakePHP autorender not stopping default view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to run a method in a controller that renders the default view on a normal browser, but renders a mobile view when the request is coming from a mobile device.

In app_controller.php

```
function beforeFilter() { 
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isMobile()) {
        $this->is_mobile = true;
        $this->set('is_mobile', true );
        $this->autoRender = false;
    }
}
```

and in the controller:

```
function home(){    
    ...bunch of data grabbing stuff...

    if ($this->is_mobile){
        $this->autoRender = NULL;
        $this->layout = 'empty';
        $this->render('/mobile/home');
    } else {
        $this->layout = 'default';
    }
}
```

When i hit it on a browser (user agent switched to mobile device) it renders the proper mobile/home view file, BUT it ALSO renders the normal, non-mobile view file underneath. Turned on debug, nothing out of the ordinary, except the 2nd, 'normal' view file is being rendered underneath the mysql trace from the mobile view.

Any thoughts on how to fully disable the default view from rendering and just showing the mobile?

Comment: Are you able to share a screenshot?

Comment: [Screenshot here](http://cl.ly/image/0y3f23023M0B)

Comment: try autoLayout = false

Comment: That didn't work - still rendered the 'default' view, but stripped the css from the page for whatever reason.

Comment: Inside your controller, you're setting `$this->autoRender` to `NULL`, not `false`?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing the rendering of a fatal error generated after your view. Setting `autoRender` to anything whilst calling render explicitly will do absolutely nothing.

Comment: autoRender = false will prevent the view from being rendered.  If you want a different view to be rendered, just call render.. and take autoRender out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

CakePHP omits options if they are 'false'; You need to change your code like so:

```
<?php

$this->autoRender = false;

?>
```

That should stop the view from rendering;

Answer (score 4):

if you want to make autorender off for specific view then add

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

in a specific method rather then in app controller